# How do I refresh the position of an object in a canvas using vue and socket.io?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm creating a 2d pong using vue.js and socket.io. For now, I just have a black rectangle in a canvas. I want it to move following the cursor of my mouse. My problem is that everything seems to work, my console.logs display the right coordinates but the position of the rectangle itself only change when I refresh the page.
(I also have buttons to move the rectangle but they're not used in this case.)

This is my .vue :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas @mousemove="mouseMove" ref="game" width="640" height="480" style="border: 1px solid black;">

    </canvas>
    <p style = "display: flex; justify-content: space-around;">
        <button v-on:click="move('right')">Right</button>
        <button v-on:click="move('left')">Left</button>
        <button v-on:click="move('up')">Up</button>
        <button v-on:click="move('down')">Down</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import io from "socket.io-client";
    export default {
        name: 'BlockGame',
        data() {
            return {
                socket: {},
                context: {},
                position: {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0
                }
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
        },
        mounted() {
            this.context = this.$refs.game.getContext("2d");
            this.socket.on("position", data => {
                this.position = data;

                console.log(data);
                
                this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.$refs.game.width, this.$refs.game.height)
                console.log("mounted pos:" + this.position.x, this.position.y);
                this.context.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, 20, 20);
            });
        },
        methods: {
            move(direction) {
                this.socket.emit("move", direction);
            },
            mouseMove() {
                this.socket.emit("mouseMove", event.clientX, event.clientY)
                console.log("event pos:" + event.clientX, event.clientY);
                console.log("position pos:" + this.position.x, this.position.y);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

And this is my app.js :

```
const Express = require("express");
const Http = require("http").Server(Express);
const SocketIo = require("socket.io")(Http, {
    cors: {
      origin: "http://localhost:8080",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
  });

var position = {
    x: 200,
    y: 200
}

SocketIo.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.emit("position", position)
    socket.on("move", data => {
        switch(data) {
            case "left":
                if (position.x - 5  < 0)
                    position.x = 0;
                else
                    position.x -= 5;
                SocketIo.emit("position", position);
                break;
            case "right":
                if (position.x + 5  >= 620)
                    position.x = 620;
                else
                    position.x += 5;
                SocketIo.emit("position", position);
                break;
            case "up":
                if (position.y - 5  < 0)
                    position.y = 0;
                else
                    position.y -= 5;
                SocketIo.emit("position", position);
                break;
            case "down":
                if (position.y + 5  >= 460)
                    position.y = 460;
                else
                    position.y += 5;
                SocketIo.emit("position", position);
                break;
        }
    })
    socket.on("mouseMove", (mousePosx, mousePosy) => {
        position.x = mousePosx;
        console.log("mousePosx:" + mousePosx)
        position.y = mousePosy;
        console.log("mousePosy:" + mousePosy)
        console.log("POSITIONposx:" + position.x)
        console.log("POSITIONposy:" + position.y)
    })
});

Http.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening at: 3000...");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer, it was actually in the code. you need to send the position to the Socket, as the following:

```
        socket.on("mouseMove", (mousePosx, mousePosy) => {
        position.x = mousePosx;
        console.log("mousePosx:" + mousePosx)
        position.y = mousePosy;
        SocketIo.emit("position", position);
        console.log("mousePosy:" + mousePosy)
        console.log("POSITIONposx:" + position.x)
        console.log("POSITIONposy:" + position.y)
    })
```

the important thing here is

```
        SocketIo.emit("position", position);
```